# How to control admin access in Joomla!?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am working on an online shopping website with Joomla! 2.5. I have installed VirtueMart as the shopping component. I want to create a user who can *only* view just the VirtueMart component's back-end after logging into the back-end of the system. That user should not be able to view any other admin controls. Is there anyway to do this using Joomla! without customizing the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the ACL in Joomla:

- Create a new group, e.g. VMUsers,
- Set "manager" as it's parent since this has the least admin priviliges
- Go through each extra section of the admin that you want to hide, i.e. Article manager, Media Manager, User Manager and in each one click on the "Options" button, click on "Permissions" tab and select "Denied" for each permission for the newly created group. You may have to do this for a few components also.

[image]

and here is what I see in the admin for the new user I placed in the VMUsers group:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using `ACL` in Joomla administrator without modifying any codes.

1. Login to Joomla administrator.
2. `Site -> Global Configuration -> Permissions.` Here you can see the `Joomla ACL controls`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

These screenshots may guide you how to change the permissions from administrator.

If you want to learn more about Joomla ACL access [clickhere](http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/2.5/Tutorial)

Try it.....

Comment: Thank you very much..but what I really wanted to know how to control the back end access permissions.